# how to execute update queries without using tsanames.ora through C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am working on C#,.net application using Oracle database.how to execute update queries without using tsanames.ora through C#.

For Ref#. following is my code

```
OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection();

string strQuery = "Update emp set Name = 'xxx' where Id='1000'";

objConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)     (HOST=xxxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxx)));User Id=xxx;Password=xxxxx;"

objConn.Open();
objCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, objConn);


if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

`

Connection is successfully gets open. but it's get stuck on objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()/objCommand.ExecuteScalar() line. I have added code in try catch block but it's not throwing any error and execution stucks on this line.

Comment: Your code looks fine - how do you know execution is getting stuck here?  Does the data in the database not get updated?  Does the user you're connecting as have sufficient rights?

Comment: you can use connection string like this in the .config file I currently do this connecting to Oracle Database
`<add name="DbConn" connectionString="Data Source=YourDataSource;User Id=YourUserId;Password=YourPassword;"/>`